# android camera function getcameraIdlist() function does not return anything

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-permissions

1. The code produces an `IllegalArguementException`.
2. The list does not seem to populate even though all `permissions` are given in the `manifest`.
3. The *application crashes* as soon as the `Activity` is opened.

   public class photo extends Activity {
               private Handler mhandler;
               public CameraDevice cam;
               private CameraDevice.StateCallback mcallback;

   ```
   public void setCallback(CameraDevice.StateCallback callback) {
       this.mcallback = callback;
   }

   public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
       this.mhandler = handler;
   }


   int count=0;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main_photo);

       String[] list=new String[10];
       CameraManager camera = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

       setCallback(mcallback);
       setHandler(mhandler);
        ListView cami = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

       ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main_photo, R.id.textView2, list);

       cami.setAdapter(adapter);

       try

       {
           list = camera.getCameraIdList();
           count++;

       } catch (CameraAccessException e)

       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }




          try

           {
               camera.openCamera(list[0], mcallback, mhandler);
               mcallback.onOpened(cam);


           } catch (CameraAccessException e)

           {
               e.printStackTrace();

               Log.d("Photo", "Error in opening camera");
           } catch (IllegalArgumentException a)

           {
               Log.d("Callback", "Callback Problem");
           }

       }
   ```

Comment: Which call produces the said exception?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, as far as I can tell mhandler and mcallback are both null in your calls to `setCallback(mcallback)` and `setHandler(mhandler)`. Try verifying these two variables before you call `camera.openCamera(list[0], mcallback, mhandler)`.

As a side note, the array `String[] list=new String[10]` is never used and your variable is reassigned 7 lines later. Maybe instead, use `String[] list;` Then 7 lines later, use `list = camera.getCameraIdList();` Or simply `String[] list=camera.getCameraIdList();`